# Is there an inbuilt constant for Anchor discriminator size?

Tags: anchor, rust

I know I can [use `InitSpace` to automatically calculate space for an account](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/derive.InitSpace.html).

I know InitSpace doesn't include the Anchor discriminator, so I still to add another 8 bytes for the discriminator. I can add a constant for ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR_SIZE:

```
#[constant]
pub const ANCHOR_DISCRIMINATOR_SIZE: usize = 8;
```

But requiring every Anchor developer to create this constant, or use [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-are-magic-numbers-and-why-do-some-consider-them-bad), seems very odd. **Is there an inbuilt constant for Anchor discriminator size?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve looked through anchor’s repo.

There’s no any constant value written in the rust code to declare discriminator is 8 bytes long.

But in anchor’s TypeScript client there’s a constant value for [DISCRIMINATOR_SIZE](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/dbb36d211c754b4d1ffbaf654ef294ec41942156/ts/packages/anchor/src/coder/borsh/discriminator.ts#L6).

Maybe try opening up an issue in anchor’s [repo](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues) they can help you more on this.